# tidyr::gather can't find my value variables

Tags: r, tidyr

I have an extremely large data.frame. I reproduce part of it.

```
     RECORDING_SESSION_LABEL condition TRIAL_INDEX IA_LABEL IA_DWELL_TIME
1                         23     match           1     eyes          3580
2                         23     match           1     nose          2410
3                         23     match           1    mouth          1442
4                         23     match           1     face           841
5                         23  mismatch           3     eyes          1817
6                         23  mismatch           3     nose          1724
7                         23  mismatch           3    mouth          1600
8                         23  mismatch           3     face          1136
9                         23  mismatch           4     eyes          4812
10                        23  mismatch           4     nose          3710
11                        23  mismatch           4    mouth          4684
12                        23  mismatch           4     face          1557
13                        23  mismatch           6     eyes          4645
14                        23  mismatch           6     nose          2321
15                        23  mismatch           6    mouth           674
16                        23  mismatch           6     face           684
17                        23     match           7     eyes          1062
18                        23     match           7     nose          1359
19                        23     match           7    mouth           215
20                        23     match           7     face             0
```

I need to calculate the percentage of IA_DWELL_TIME for each IA_LABEL in each trial index. For that, I first put IA_label in different columns

```
data_IA_DWELL_TIME <- tidyr::spread(data_IA_DWELL_TIME, key = IA_LABEL, value = IA_DWELL_TIME)
```

For calculating the percentage, I create a new dataframe:

```
data_IA_DWELL_TIME_percentage <-data_IA_DWELL_TIME
data_IA_DWELL_TIME_percentage$eyes <- 100*(data_IA_DWELL_TIME$eyes/(rowSums(data_IA_DWELL_TIME[,c("eyes","nose","mouth","face")])))
data_IA_DWELL_TIME_percentage$nose <- 100*(data_IA_DWELL_TIME$nose/(rowSums(data_IA_DWELL_TIME[,c("eyes","nose","mouth","face")])))
data_IA_DWELL_TIME_percentage$mouth <- 100*(data_IA_DWELL_TIME$mouth/(rowSums(data_IA_DWELL_TIME[,c("eyes","nose","mouth","face")])))
data_IA_DWELL_TIME_percentage$face <- 100*(data_IA_DWELL_TIME$face/(rowSums(data_IA_DWELL_TIME[,c("eyes","nose","mouth","face")])))
```

So all is fine, and I get the wanted output. The problem is when I want to put the columns back to the rows

```
data_IA_DWELL_TIME_percentage <- tidyr::gather(key = IA_LABEL, value = IA_DWELL_TIME,-RECORDING_SESSION_LABEL,-condition, -TRIAL_INDEX)
```

I obtain this error:

> Error in tidyr::gather(key = IA_LABEL, value = IA_DWELL_TIME,
>   -RECORDING_SESSION_LABEL,  :    object 'RECORDING_SESSION_LABEL' not found
>   >

Any idea of what is going on here? Thanks!

Comment: You need to refer to your `df`, e.g. `data_IA_DWELL_TIME_percentage <- tidyr::gather(data_IA_DWELL_TIME_percentage, key = IA_LABEL, value = IA_DWELL_TIME,-RECORDING_SESSION_LABEL,-condition, -TRIAL_INDEX)`

Comment: What an stupid error! Thanks a lot arg0naut91

Comment: No problem, we're all learning here - see below for a possible improvement of your pipeline as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained, you're not referring to your data frame in the `gather` statement.

However, you could avoid the need for referring to it altogether and put the second part in a `dplyr` pipeline, like below:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

data_IA_DWELL_TIME <- spread(data_IA_DWELL_TIME, key = IA_LABEL, value = IA_DWELL_TIME) 

data_IA_DWELL_TIME %>%
  mutate_at(
    vars(eyes, nose, mouth, face),
    ~ 100 * (. / (rowSums(data_IA_DWELL_TIME[, c("eyes", "nose", "mouth", "face")])))
  ) %>%
  gather(key = IA_LABEL, value = IA_DWELL_TIME,-RECORDING_SESSION_LABEL,-condition, -TRIAL_INDEX)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot arg0naut91. Really helpful advice!